# Post Request for transfering file with content type multipart/form-data"

Tags: api, rest

I'm trying to connect to an **REST API** endpoint to transfer files.
The endpoint requires the data beeing sent as multipart/form-data
So far I'm only used to sending files as binary data and somehow I'm lost.

That's their example **POST request**:

```
curl https://api.lexoffice.io/v1/files
-X POST
-H "Authorization: Bearer {accessToken}"
-H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"
-H "Accept: application/json"
-F "file=@{PathToFile}" -F "type=voucher"
```

I also tested it with a chrome REST API client extension, but there when selecting multipart/form-data you can upload your file to the extention before it's transferred, which works perfectly.

Now I have my file sitting somewhere accessible via the internet. Let's just take https://homematic-ip.com/sites/default/files/downloads/hmip-srh_um_web.pdf as an example.

**How could I transfer this file now to the endpoint?**

I searched a lot but somehow didn't found anything that would help me.

Any help is greatly appreciated.